# Add style to a javascript button

Tags: javascript, qliksense

i have a javascript code that i would like to add a simple style to the buttons. Even if i have to add css please let me know where to add it and using which line. Thanks.

Comment: Did you even google this? You're probably not the first person ever who wants to style a button. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-guide-to-styling-buttons-using-css-f64d4f96337f

Answer (score -1):

I have a javascript code that I would like to add a simple style to the buttons. Even if I have to add CSS please let me know where to add it and using which line. Thanks.

```
define(["jquery","qlik"], function($, qlik) {


return {

  initialProperties: {
        version: 1.0,
        var_to_use: "vButtonValue",
        num_of_buttons: "1",
        buttonname1: "  YTD  ",
        buttonname2: "  MTD  ",
        buttonname3: " TODAY ",
        buttonname4: " Clear ",
        buttonname5: "Button 5",
        buttonvalue1: "1",
        buttonvalue2: "2",
        buttonvalue3: "3",
        buttonvalue4: "4",
        buttonvalue5: "5"   
    },
    //property panel
    definition: {
        type: "items",
        component: "accordion",
        items: {
            settings: {
                uses: "settings",
                items : {
                    usevariable : {
                        ref : "var_to_use",
                        expression:"optional",
                        label : "Variable to use",
                        type : "string",
                        defaultValue : "vButtonValue"
                    },
                    usevariable2 : {
                        ref : "num_of_buttons",
                        expression:"",
                        label : "Number of buttons",
                        type : "integer",
                        component: "dropdown",
                        defaultValue : "1",
                        max:5,
                        options: 
                            [ {
                                value: "1",
                                label: "1"
                            }, {
                                value: "2",
                                label: "2"
                            }, {
                                value: "3",
                                label: "3"
                            }, {
                                value: "4",
                                label: "4"
                            }, {
                                value: "5",
                                label: "5"
                            }],
                    },

                    usevariable4 : {
                      label : "Button Values",
                      ref : "button_value_block",
                      settings: {
                            uses: "settings",

                                items : {

                                    buttonvalue1p : {
                                        ref : "buttonvalue1",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button value 1",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "1"
                                    },
                                    buttonvalue2p : {
                                        ref : "buttonvalue2",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button value 2",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "2"
                                    },
                                    buttonvalue3p : {
                                        ref : "buttonvalue3",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button value 3",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "3"
                                    },
                                    buttonvalue4p : {
                                        ref : "buttonvalue4",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button value 4",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "4"
                                    },
                                    buttonvalue5p : {
                                        ref : "buttonvalue5",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button value 5",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "5"
                                    }
                                }
                      }
                    },

                    usevariable3 : {
                      label : "Button Names",
                      ref : "button_names_block",
                      settings: {
                            uses: "settings",

                                items : {

                                    buttonname1p : {
                                        ref : "buttonname1",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button name 1",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "Button 1"
                                    },
                                    buttonname2p : {
                                        ref : "buttonname2",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button name 2",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "Button 2"
                                    },
                                    buttonname3p : {
                                        ref : "buttonname3",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button name 3",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "Button 3"
                                    },
                                    buttonname4p : {
                                        ref : "buttonname4",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button name 4",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "Button 4"
                                    },
                                    buttonname5p : {
                                        ref : "buttonname5",
                                        expression:"optional",
                                        label : "Button name 5",
                                        type : "string",
                                        defaultValue : "Button 5"
                                    }

                                }
                      },



                }
            }

            }
        }
    },
    snapshot: {
        canTakeSnapshot: false
    },

    paint: function ($element,layout) {

      var numbuttons=layout.num_of_buttons;
      var numbuttonsmax=parseFloat(numbuttons)+1;


     if (numbuttonsmax > 6) {
            numbuttonsmax = 6;
      };

      var html='<div width="100%">';
      var i = 0;
      var idbutnom='hola';

      for (i = 1; i < numbuttonsmax; i++) {

         switch(i) {
                case 1:
                    idbutnom=layout.buttonname1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    idbutnom=layout.buttonname2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    idbutnom=layout.buttonname3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    idbutnom=layout.buttonname4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    idbutnom=layout.buttonname5;
                    break;
            };

         html=html+"<button class='qirby-button' width='auto' id='button" + i + "'>" + idbutnom + "</button>"    

      };

      html=html+"</div>";

      $element.html(html);


      $element.find("#button1").on("qv-activate", function() {

                var app = qlik.currApp();
                var textobus=layout.var_to_use;
                app.variable.setContent(textobus, layout.buttonvalue1);

      });

      $element.find("#button2").on("qv-activate", function() {

                var app = qlik.currApp();
                var textobus=layout.var_to_use;
                app.variable.setContent(textobus, layout.buttonvalue2);

      });

      $element.find("#button3").on("qv-activate", function() {

                var app = qlik.currApp();
                var textobus=layout.var_to_use;
                app.variable.setContent(textobus, layout.buttonvalue3);

      });
      $element.find("#button4").on("qv-activate", function() {

                var app = qlik.currApp();
                var textobus=layout.var_to_use;
                app.variable.setContent(textobus, layout.buttonvalue4);

      });

      $element.find("#button5").on("qv-activate", function() {

                var app = qlik.currApp();
                var textobus=layout.var_to_use;
                app.variable.setContent(textobus, layout.buttonvalue5);

      });       
     }

     }
});
```